# T-SQL, cut string into chunks of 35 characters without cutting words

Tags: t-sql, string-concatenation

OK, I have been searching everywhere for a right syntax.
Say I have a string of unknown length
i.e.  'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'

I need to split it into a chunks of up to 35 characters each like : 'The quick brown fox jumps over the'
space is a delimiter.

rules are:

## 1 - each chunk is 35 character or less

## 2 - DO NOT split words.

2.1 - if combined length is greater than 35, go back until you find the first space where length under 35 and cut it there.

## 3 - result set must return a table with 5 values (made up of the string chunks) and a row number indicating result of more than one record if needed. (see table below)

that is if a string divides into 5 35 char chunks one record return
any excess spills over into more rows in set of 5

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________|
|level  |   Val1                            |Val2                           |   Val3                        |   Val4                            |   Val5                        |
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________|
|   1   |The quick brown fox jumps over the | lazy dog. The quick brown fox | jumps over the lazy dog. The  | quick brown fox jumps over the    | lazy dog. The quick brown fox |
|   2   | jumps over the lazy dog. The      | quick brown fox jumps over the| lazy dog.                     |NULL                               |   NULL                        |       
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________|
```

I found some code here that kind of work  but I can not get result limited to 35 char chunks

what it does is:
get count of delimiters in the string (number of spaces)
than split all using CTE into table.
than concatenate all back. but, in "Splitvalues" cte if I break the mainLevel into chanks of 5 it works but only joining not by length , but by group of 5
and I still lost on how to pivot the result into 6 column as described.

```
DECLARE     @ColumnLen             INT           = 35
       ,@BNotAllowNullinValue1 BIT           = 1
       ,@Delim                 VARCHAR(5)    = SPACE(1)
       ,@DelimCount            INT
       ,@OriginalStr           NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
       ,@ReturnColumnCount     INT           = 5

SET @OriginalStr = @OriginalStr + @Delim
SET @DelimCount = ((LEN(@OriginalStr + '|')-1) - (LEN(REPLACE(@OriginalStr + '|',@Delim,''))-1)) / LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Delim)) + '|')

---- test data
;WITH Splitvalues(SplitValue ,MainLevel ,ProcessLevel,LastPos,Original)
AS (SELECT TOP 1 LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@OriginalStr,1,ABS(CHARINDEX(@Delim,@OriginalStr,1)))))
                ,1 as MainLevel
                ,1 as ProcessLevel
                ,CHARINDEX(@Delim,@OriginalStr,1 + 1) AS LastPos
                ,@OriginalStr
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@OriginalStr,LastPos + 1,ABS((CHARINDEX(@Delim,@OriginalStr,LastPos + 1) - LastPos)))))
          ,CASE (ProcessLevel % 5) WHEN  0 THEN MainLevel +1 ELSE MainLevel END  as MainLevel
          ,ProcessLevel + 1 as ProcessLevel
         ,CHARINDEX(@Delim,@OriginalStr,LastPos + 1) AS LastPos
          ,@OriginalStr
    FROM Splitvalues
    WHERE ProcessLevel <= @DelimCount
          AND ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@OriginalStr,LastPos + 1,ABS((CHARINDEX(@Delim,@OriginalStr,LastPos + 1) - LastPos))))),'') <> '')
---- actual query;
,cte(MainLevel,ProcessLevel,combined,rn)
     AS (SELECT MainLevel,ProcessLevel,Splitvalue ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MainLevel ORDER BY MainLevel,ProcessLevel)FROM Splitvalues)
,cte2(MainLevel,ProcessLevel ,finalstatus ,rn)
     AS (SELECT MainLevel,cte.ProcessLevel ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),combined)  ,1 FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte2.MainLevel,cte2.ProcessLevel  +1 ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),cte2.finalstatus + @Delim + cte.combined+ @Delim )
               ,cte2.rn + 1
         FROM cte2
         INNER JOIN cte ON cte.MainLevel = cte2.MainLevel  AND cte.rn = cte2.rn + 1
        )
     SELECT MainLevel,MAX(finalstatus),LEN(MAX(finalstatus)+'|')
     FROM cte2
     GROUP BY MainLevel
```

thanks for all the help.

Comment: what is the rules on adding final code here?  do I use Answer my onw question ? even though I accepted one of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the place to cut I would suggest getting the first 35 characters of the string, and then find the last space. This could be done using reverse and charindex:

The position of the rightmost space is:

```
36-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@txt, 36)))
```

Now I would then use a recursive CTE. Each level would cut of the next bit af the string until it is empty.

I've included the query below, where I anchor the CTE using the placement finder from above, and in the recursive part, i again use the place finder.

The recursion ends when there is no remaining character.

Finally, to set it up in 5 columns on a row, I have numbered each occurence 0...n

I then use the fact than  n%5 modulus is in (0,1,2,3,4)
and that n/5 as integer division gives the row number where the column should be output.

```
declare @txt varchar(max)=N'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
;
WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        TRIM(LEFT(@txt, n)) grp
       ,0 grpn
       ,TRIM(SUBSTRING(@txt, n + 1, LEN(@txt))) remainder
    FROM (SELECT
            36 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@txt, 36))) n) a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        TRIM(LEFT(remainder, (n))) grp
       ,grpn + 1
       ,TRIM(SUBSTRING(remainder, (n) + 1, LEN(remainder))) remainder
    FROM cte
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT
            36 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(remainder, 36))) n) a
    WHERE LEN(remainder) > 0)
SELECT
    max(iif(grpn%5=0,grp,null)) Val1
    ,max(iif(grpn%5=1,grp,null)) Val2
    ,max(iif(grpn%5=2,grp,null)) Val3
    ,max(iif(grpn%5=3,grp,null)) Val4
    ,max(iif(grpn%5=4,grp,null)) Val5
FROM cte
group by grpn/5
```

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer. based on Søren Kongstad example I was able to build a workable function.  thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If your version of MS Sql Server is 2017 or later, then you could use STRING_SPLIT & STRING_AGG for this.

**Example:**

> ```
> declare @OriginalStr nvarchar(max);
> set @OriginalStr = N'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
>
> declare @ColumnLen int = 35;
>
> declare @parts table 
> (
>   part_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   part_content nvarchar(max)
> );
>
> declare @lines table 
> (
>   line_id int primary key,
>   line_content nvarchar(max)
> );
>
> -- splitting the string on the spaces
> insert into @parts (part_content)
> select value
> from string_split(@OriginalStr, ' ') spl
>
> -- glueing the parts back together
> insert into @lines (line_id, line_content)
> select 
>  lineNr,
>  string_agg(part_content, ' ') as line
> from
> (
>   select part_content
>   , floor(1.0*(sum(len(part_content)+1) 
>                over (order by part_id))/(@ColumnLen-1))+1 as lineNr
>   from @parts 
> ) q
> group by lineNr;
>
> -- pivoting the lines
> select
> ceiling((line_id-0.1)/5) as [Level],
> max(case when line_id%5 = 1 then line_content end) as Val1,
> max(case when line_id%5 = 2 then line_content end) as Val2,
> max(case when line_id%5 = 3 then line_content end) as Val3,
> max(case when line_id%5 = 4 then line_content end) as Val4,
> max(case when line_id%5 = 0 then line_content end) as Val5
> from @lines l
> group by ceiling((line_id-0.1)/5)
> order by [Level];
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Level | Val1                              | Val2                              | Val3                               | Val4                               | Val5                          
> :---- | :-------------------------------- | :-------------------------------- | :--------------------------------- | :--------------------------------- | :-----------------------------
> 1     | The quick brown fox jumps over    | the lazy dog. The quick brown fox | jumps over the lazy dog. The quick | brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. | The quick brown fox jumps over
> 2     | the lazy dog. The quick brown fox | jumps over the lazy dog           | null                               | null                               | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2243e14b96b3ee34318005d1462f3ee)*

On an older version of Sql Server, this should work to fill the table variable for the lines.

```
with rcte as
(
   select 
   1 as lineNr,
   1 as strPos,
   @ColumnLen + 1 - cast(
     charindex(N' ',
       reverse(
         substring(@OriginalStr, 1, @ColumnLen)
       ) 
     ) as int) as lineLen
   
   union all
   
   select
   lineNr + 1,
   strPos + lineLen,
   @ColumnLen + 1 - cast(
     charindex(N' ',
       reverse(
         substring(@OriginalStr, strPos+lineLen, @ColumnLen)
       )
     ) as int)
   from rcte
   where strPos+lineLen < len(@OriginalStr)
)
insert into @lines (line_id, line_content)
select 
 lineNr,
 line = rtrim(substring(@OriginalStr, pos, lineLen))
from rcte;
```

Comment: thank you LukStorms, however company policies prevent me doing this as not all of the clients are up to the latest and greatests.

Comment: @vlad Thx, and I understand. Well, I added my version of a recursive CTE to the answer anyway.  It takes a slightly different approach, by first calculating the positions and lengths of the lines.

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."